# Proving the existence of the third-order derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, functions

The statement is as follows:

Let $f ∶ R → R$ be a function such that $f′′′$ exists. Suppose a < b are real numbers such
that f(a) = f(b) = f′(a) = f′(b) = 0.
Then there exists c ∈ (a, b) such that f′′′(c) = 0.

** I am trying to formulate a proof in this way:
$f'''(c)$ = 0 indicating $\frac{f''(b)-f''(a)} {b-a}$ = 0 for some a,b

and it follows that $f''(b) = f''(a)$

Apply the Mean Value Theorem again we needs to prove $ \frac{f'(x)-f'(a)}{x-a}$ equals $\frac{f'(x)-f'(b)}{x-b}$

And I had a feeling that I use the condition  f(a) = f(b) = f′(a) = f′(b) = 0, but how?

Comment: This sounds like a job for the intermediate value theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f(a)=f(b)=0$, by Rolle's theorem there is $c_1\in (a,b)$ with $f'(c_1)=0$. Same argument gives $c_2\in (a,c_1)$ and $c_3\in (c_1,b)$ with $f''(c_2)=f''(c_3)=0$ (because $f'(a)=f'(c_1)=f'(b)=0$). Repeat again and get $c\in (c_2,c_3)$ with $f'''(c)=0$.